# Node.js application crashing

Tags: javascript, node.js, pusher

I am just beginning with node.js and was trying to deploy Pusher's example authentication code but it fails
Here is the code -

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var Pusher = require( 'pusher' );

var app = express( express.logger() );
app.use( express.bodyParser() );

var pusher = new Pusher( { appId: '<appid>', key:'<key>', secret:'<secret>' } );

app.post( '/pusher/auth', function( req, res ) {
  var socketId = req.body.socket_id;
  var channel = req.body.channel_name;
  var auth = pusher.auth( socketId, channel );
  res.send( auth );
} );

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen( port );
```

Executing node messaging-server.js throws the following -

```
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/messaging_server$ node messaging-server.js 
Error: Most middleware (like logger) is no longer bundled with Express and must be   installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (~/Desktop/messaging_server/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:89:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (~/Desktop/messaging_server/messaging-server.js:11:28)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

How do I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have express 4 installed, but Pusher's docs are using an older version of express.  Let's use [`morgan`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/morgan) to replace the now-defunct `express.logger()`:

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var Pusher = require( 'pusher' );
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = express( logger() );
app.use( express.bodyParser() );

var pusher = new Pusher( { appId: '<appid>', key:'<key>', secret:'<secret>' } );

app.post( '/pusher/auth', function( req, res ) {
  var socketId = req.body.socket_id;
  var channel = req.body.channel_name;
  var auth = pusher.auth( socketId, channel );
  res.send( auth );
} );

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen( port );
```

(Don't forget to run `npm install morgan`)

Comment: I also needed to install body-parser in addition to morgan.